# Criar tabela a partir de um array fazendo das chaves o cabeçalho

Tags: php, array

Olá. No sistema que eu estou desenvolvendo tenho a possibilidade de criar filtros para as consultas, mas as consultas nem sempre possuem como resultado as mesmas colunas. O resultado é armazenado em um array de chave-valor, onde a chave é o nome de cada coluna do BD.

Exemplo de resultado da consulta:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [indicador] => Precipitação total
            [fonte_de_dados] => INMET
            [microrregiao] => Campanha Meridional
            [sigla_uf] => RS
            [mes_coleta] => 1/2020
            [valor] => 0.140
            [unidade] => mm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [indicador] => Precipitação total
            [fonte_de_dados] => INMET
            [microrregiao] => Caxias do Sul
            [sigla_uf] => RS
            [mes_coleta] => 1/2020
            [valor] => 0.194
            [unidade] => mm
        )

)
```

Tendo isso em vista, para evitar diversos "`if...else`", pretendo exibir num primeiro momento em uma tabela o nome de cada chave (indicador, fonte_de_dados,...) como cabeçalho de uma tabela e os valores nas células, como no exemplo abaixo.

[image: Exemplo de tabela]

Como posso fazer cabeçalho da tabela com as chaves? Meu `foreach` está da seguinte forma:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
   <?php
      foreach ($registros as $chave => $registro) {
         echo "<tr>";
         foreach ($registros[$chave] as $celula) {
             echo "<td>" . $celula . "</td>";
         }
         echo "</tr>";
      }
   ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Se você fizer um `foreach($array as $key => $value` e imprimir cada `'<td>'. $key .'</td>'`, n resolve?

Comment: O valor é chamado pela chave: `$celula['indicador'];`, e um array das chaves pode ser através de `array_keys($celula);`

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você precisaria verificar se $registros não está vazio e recuperar as chaves do primeiro item de $registros. Segue um exemplo.

Array Keys - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Sintaxe alternativa (if e foreach) - https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php

$registros = [
        [
        'indicador' => 'Precipitação total',
        'fonte_de_dados' => 'INMET',
        'microrregiao' => 'Campanha Meridional',
        'sigla_uf' => 'RS',
        'mes_coleta' => '1/2020',
        'valor' => '0.140',
        'unidade' => 'mm',
    ],
    [
        'indicador' => 'Precipitação total',
        'fonte_de_dados' => 'INMET',
        'microrregiao' => 'Caxias do Sul',
        'sigla_uf' => 'RS',
        'mes_coleta' => '1/2020',
        'valor' => '0.194',
        'unidade' => 'mm',
    ]
];
?>


<?php

    if (!empty($registros)):
?>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach (array_keys($registros[0]) as $cabecalho):
                    echo "<th>{$cabecalho}</th>";
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

<?php

        foreach ($registros as $chave => $registro):

            echo "<tr>";

            foreach ($registros[$chave] as $celula):
                echo "<td>" . $celula . "</td>";
            endforeach;

            echo "</tr>";

        endforeach;
        
    else:
        echo "SEM RESULTADOS";
    endif;
?>

    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado, Marcos.